# Why is my processor "TurboBoosting"

Tags: windows-7, cpu, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

Below is a screenshot of my computer screen five minutes after I log on.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, my processor is turbocharging, and its the only process using the CPU.

Whats going on here?  Why is this happening?

Comment: There are some processes that do not show in task manager, interrupt requests, for example. Open Resource Monitor to see if anything hidden is using cpu clock cycles when TB is spiking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what the issue is. Turbo-boosting happens automatically when your processor decides that it can increase the clock cycle count, that such increasing is "needed" and that it does not violate some power constraints (if you are on a laptop that is not plugged int, you can set it so that it will never turbo-boost for example).

If your program "needs" the extra speed, and your processor is giving it, everything is working as it should.

Comment: What program needed extra speed?  I posted the picture because according to the task manager, the Turbo Boosing meter is the only process using any CPU power.

Comment: If the program was maxing out a core, and I/O was not the bottleneck, it would boost it. Could be that the meter is just really badly written to take up that much power.

Comment: So its wrong to assume that when Intel makes a program to monitor its hardware, its a well written program?

Comment: See if you can reporduce the issue. I have no idea how intel's program was written

Comment: @wizlog - Why do you care?  Turbo-boosting is a good thing not a bad thing.

Comment: @Ramhound: The increased fan speed sometimes is a bit of a bother.